# STM32F407 Timer Interrupt

Tags: c, timer, freertos, stm32f4discovery, usart

I working on STM32F4-Discovery with FreeRTOS v9. I have 2 tasks, task 1 is for blinking the LED, and task 2 I use for etherenet connection using LwIP.

Task 1

```
void test_print(void)
{
    TickType_t wake_time,tamp1,tamp2;
    const uint32_t period = 100;
    char buff[32];

    wake_time = xTaskGetTickCount();
    while(1)
    {
        USART_puts("aaaaaaaaaaa\n ");
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_13);
        delay_dw(500); //This is just my own function delay
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_13);
        delay_dw(500);
    }
}
```

Task 2

```
void echo_tcp()
{
    int c1,c2;
    char clock[32],tmp[32];
    tamp = 0;
    while(1)
    {
            if(ETH_CheckFrameReceived())
            {
                cycle_start();
                c1 = getCycles();
                LwIP_Pkt_Handle();      
                c2 = getCycles();
                cycle_stop();

                tamp+= c2 - c1;
                GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_12);
                delay_dw(2000);
                GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_12);
                delay_dw(2000);
            }
            else
            {
                GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD,GPIO_Pin_12);
                LwIP_Periodic_Handle(LocalTime);
            }
    }
}
```

I using a timer function for interrupt. The purpose of interrupt on this case is to show me about the cycle of the Task 2 every 1 second when I gives some connection load while 2 Tasks are running together.

This is my interrupt configuration

```
void TIM2_Config(){
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div16);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2,ENABLE);
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 42000-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 200-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2,&TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2,ENABLE);
}   


void TIM_IT_Enable(){
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2,TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
}
void NVIC_Config(){
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStrurture;
    NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_0);
    NVIC_InitStrurture.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStrurture.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0x00;
    NVIC_InitStrurture.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x00;
    NVIC_InitStrurture.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd =ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStrurture);
}

int nInterrupt=0,counter;
char buffer[32];
char buf_temp[32];
void TIM2_IRQHandler(){
    if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2,TIM_IT_Update)!=RESET){
        TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2,TIM_IT_Update);
        nInterrupt++;
        //USART_puts("Interrupt!!\n");

        sprintf(buf_temp,"%d\n",temp); //tamp is int variable
        USART_puts(buf_temp); //BUG IN HERE

        temp = 0;
    }
}
```

When I compile it and upload it on my STM32F4-Discovery all the tasks are not running, but when I command (disabled) the usart function on my TIM2_IRQHandler() function all the tasks are working well. If I do so, I can't see about the cycle of my Task. Anyone help please??

Sorry for bad English

Regards, Rama

Comment: Do you think the time between timer interrupts is sufficient to get the USART output done before the next interrupt arrives? If not, your program might end up doing nothing but USART. To diagnose you can try to (extremely) increase the period of the timer or print only a single letter, or both.

Comment: Yeah.. it depends on what USART_puts() does.   Presumably, the USART driver is also interrupt-driven?  It's 'usual' to signal out strings to a driver-handler thread and then requeue them to the other driver for the USART.  If USART_puts() is not a driver and interrupt-handlers, then as @Yunnosch correctly says, you're really stuft.

Comment: @Yunnosch I already increase the period from 1 sec until 5 sec (is it enough?) & a single letter to send. But it still not work.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit How I can know if my USART_puts() is interrupt driven??

Comment: Do you have documentation? Or maybe a support agreement? Or access to the source code? Or a contact to the author?